# how to open browser on android phone from an app on pc using java

Tags: java

I want to open an url on the default browser on android that is connected to a laptop via usb.
opening an url and also opening phone settings and else.

Comment: take the [tour] and read [ask], please

Answer (score 0):

It's super simple, all you need is ADB tunnel (correct adb driver installed on your PC as well)

To open a URL in android (default browser)

> adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d
> http://www.stackoverflow.com

To Open settings in android

> adb shell am start -a android.settings.SETTINGS

Comment: Thanks, by the way. But the things is, I dont wanna use ADB. if there is a way to do that with javax-usb or another library in java.

Comment: Then you should try scrcpy... it's an open source lib https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy

Comment: scrcpy needs ADB too. Like I said, I want to develop my own java app but I don't want to use ADB connection. may be via MTP I could open settings or other apps like samsung galaxy store or else. hope my question is clear enough. thanks.